# Order by random in RethinkDB

Tags: rethinkdb

I want to order documents randomly in RethinkDB. The reason for this is that I return `n` groups of documents and each group must appear in order in the results (so all documents belonging to a group should be placed together); and I need to randomly pick a document, belonging to the first group in the results (you don't know which is the first group in the results - the first ones could be empty, so no documents are retrieved for them).

The solution I found to this is to randomly order each of the groups before concat-ing to the result, then always pick the first document from the results (as it will be random). But I'm having a hard time ordering these groups randomly. Would appreciate any hint or even a better solution if there is one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to order a selection of documents randomly you can just use [`.orderBy`](http://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/order_by/) and return a random number using [`r.random`](http://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/#random).

```
r.db('test').table('table')
  .orderBy(function (row) { return r.random(); })
```

If these document are in a group and you want to randomize them inside the group, you can just call `orderBy` after the `group` statement.

```
r.db('test').table('table')
  .groupBy('property')
  .orderBy(function (row) { return r.random(); })
```

If you want to randomize the order of the groups, you can just call `orderBy` **after** calling [`.ungroup`](http://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/ungroup/)

```
r.db('test').table('table')
  .groupBy('property')
  .ungroup()
  .orderBy(function (row) { return r.random(); })
```

Comment: Nice, I haven't known that you can use `random` with `order_by`. Maybe you could update the docs with this fact, it's very helpful. Thank you for your detailed answer!

Comment: I'll pass that suggestions around. Glad it's useful!

Comment: how do you do this in python? is this js code since it is not working in data explorer?

Comment: This should work in the data explorer. If it doesn't make sure you have the right table, db, and property

Comment: which rethinkdb version are you guys using? this is not possible.. as mentioned by John, the sorting function must be deterministic.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer here should not be possible, as [John](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41369445/3169491) mentioned the sorting function must be deterministic, which [r.random()](https://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/random/) is not.

The [r.sample()](https://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/sample/) function could be used to return a random order of the elements:

> If the sequence has less than the requested number of elements (i.e., calling sample(10) on a sequence with only five elements), sample will return the entire sequence in a random order.

So, count the number of elements you have, and set that number as the sample number, and you'll get a randomized response.

**Example:**

```
var res = r.db("population").table("europeans")
              .filter(function(row) { 
                  return row('age').gt(18) 
              });
var num = res.count();
res.sample(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not getting this to work. I tried to sort an table randomly and I'm getting the following error:

`e: Sorting by a non-deterministic function is not supported in:
r.db("db").table("table").orderBy(function(var_33) { return r.random(); })`

Also I have read in the rethink documentation that this is not supported. This is from the rethinkdb orderBy documentation:

`Sorting functions passed to orderBy must be deterministic. You cannot, for instance, order rows using the random command. Using a non-deterministic function with orderBy will raise a ReqlQueryLogicError.`

Any suggestions on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution would be to give each document a random number:

```
r.db('db').table('table')
  .merge(doc => ({
    random: r.random(1, 10)
  })        
  .orderBy('random')
```